# Why is quanteda lookup resulting in 100% sparsity but the data is there

Tags: r, quanteda

I have created a dictionary in quanteda and prepared my corpus etc. I have wordclouds and textstat_frequencies, so I can see the text data I'm trying to match is there.

However, when I run dtm, I get some hits, but on dfm_lookup I repeatedly get 100% sparsity. What am I doing wrong?

```
doc <- data.frame(symptoms = c("patient trouble breathing", "breathlessness", "heart palpitations", 
                              "elevated troponin", "chest tightness, pericarditis", "patient drowsy, headaches, 
                            low bloood pressure", "tummy pain, vomiting", "heart attack", "edema, achypnea"))


# create corpus from main text
corp <- corpus(doc, text_field = 'symptoms')

# prerocessing: tokenise, lowercase, remove stopwords and punctuation and perform stemming
corp2 <- corp %>% 
  tokens(remove_punct = T, remove_numbers = T, remove_symbols = T) %>% 
  tokens_tolower() %>% 
  tokens_remove(stopwords('en'))
# tokens_wordstem() # this won't suit for our dictionary, e.g. acute becomes acut, etc might re-appraise
corp2

dtm <- dfm(corp2)

# construct lexicon in a dataframe
terms <- structure(list(keywords = c("myocarditis", "pericarditis", "heart","heart-attack", "chest-pain", "tightness","tummy",
                                     "irritability", "vomiting", "tachypnea",   "achypnea", "tachypnoea",   
                                     "lethargy",    "drowsiness", "drowsy"),
                        topic = c("cardiac", "cardiac","cardiac", "cardiac","cardiac", "non_specific", "non_specific",
                                  "non_specific","non_specific","non_specific", "non_specific","non_specific",
                                  "children", "children","children")) ,class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
# convert to dictionary
lex <- split(terms$keywords, terms$topic)
lex <-  (dictionary(lex))                    


# tokenise and apply dict to prepared symptom corpus
head(dfm(tokens(corp2), dictionary = lex))

dtm <- dfm(tokens(corp2), dictionary = lex)

dtm_lu <- dfm_lookup(dtm, lex, valuetype = "glob") #* get 100% sparse ? , but not above?
print(dtm_lu)

# show unmatched
dfm_lookup(dtm, lex1, nomatch = "_UNMATCHED")
```

What is the difference between

`dtm <- dfm(tokens(corp2), dictionary = lex)`

and

```
dtm_lu <- dfm_lookup(dtm, lex, valuetype = "glob")
```

What is dtm doing when you pass it both a corpus and a dictionary, is it maybe just joining them and that's why some results come back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tokens_lookup()` to apply the dictionary.  `dfm(x, dictionary = ...)` is deprecated and should not be used. Always better to use `tokens_lookup()` because this matches multi-token values in the dictionary (although you had none).

Also I simplified your code a bit.

```r
library("quanteda")
#> Package version: 3.2.3
#> Unicode version: 14.0
#> ICU version: 70.1
#> Parallel computing: 10 of 10 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

corp <- corpus(c("patient trouble breathing", "breathlessness", "heart palpitations", 
                 "elevated troponin", "chest tightness, pericarditis", "patient drowsy, headaches, 
                  low bloood pressure", "tummy pain, vomiting", "heart attack", "edema, achypnea"))

toks <- corp %>% 
  tokens(remove_punct = T, remove_numbers = T, remove_symbols = T) %>% 
  tokens_tolower() %>% 
  tokens_remove(stopwords('en'))

lex <- dictionary(list(keywords = c("myocarditis", "pericarditis", "heart","heart-attack", "chest-pain", "tightness","tummy",
                                    "irritability", "vomiting", "tachypnea",   "achypnea", "tachypnoea",   
                                    "lethargy",    "drowsiness", "drowsy"),
                       topic = c("cardiac", "cardiac","cardiac", "cardiac","cardiac", "non_specific", "non_specific",
                                 "non_specific","non_specific","non_specific", "non_specific","non_specific",
                                 "children", "children","children")))
```

Now the key difference in the code from a functional standpoint:

```r
dfmat <- toks %>%
  tokens_lookup(dictionary = lex) %>%
  dfm()
dfmat
#> Document-feature matrix of: 9 documents, 2 features (66.67% sparse) and 0 docvars.
#>        features
#> docs    keywords topic
#>   text1        0     0
#>   text2        0     0
#>   text3        1     0
#>   text4        0     0
#>   text5        2     0
#>   text6        1     0
#> [ reached max_ndoc ... 3 more documents ]
```

Comment: That worked, thanks for cleaner code also